# Change to a different DetailsTemplate on a MasterDetailsView when selection changes

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, uwp, windows-community-toolkit

In the MasterDetailView I have a list of different items. When the item is selected the appropriate DetailsTemplate must be loaded.

I have absolutely no idea how to do this!

This example is what I expect the interaction to be.

The list on the left side of the MasterDetailView is filled with pigs, chickens and gold fish.

When the user selects the pig item, then the details of the pig must appear in the details section of the MasterDetailView control.

When the user selects a Gold Fish item then the Gold Fish's details must appear.

etc.

Comment: I can't see the example

Comment: So, what have you done? You'd better provide a [mcve] here. Otherwise no one will give you a precise answer to help you solve your question.

Answer (score 0):

If your left menu listview's items are instances of IAnimal.

Just bind SelectedItem to a property SelectedAnimal on your view model.

Create a grid and place a ContentControl to host the detail view in that grid. Bind its Content to SelectedAnimal and in the Grid's Resources add a datatemplate for each animal type and map it to a View that would visualize the details you want to show for the IAnimal.

So when you click an IAnimal in the left menu it will be set to the VM SelectedAnimal property. The ContentControl will then show that IAnimal using the View defined by the DataTemplate.

I would use the same approach to define how the left menu should look for the IAnimal items in the menu list as well.

Comment: Of course if it is the same properties you want to show for all animals in the details view you can use a single datatemplate for IAnimal instead.

You may also want to look at the DataTemplateSelector for more advanced usecases.

Answer (score 0):

Add to my above comment. If you meant that you're a beginner in UWP. You just want to know how to start to use the MasterDetailsView XAML Control of the windows community toolkit. Then, the official document [Windows Community Toolkit Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/) would be a good start.

And the windows community toolkit also has a complete code sample for each controls. The samples are on [github](https://github.com/windows-toolkit/WindowsCommunityToolkit). For the MasterDetalsView is [here](https://github.com/windows-toolkit/WindowsCommunityToolkit/tree/master/Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.SampleApp/SamplePages/MasterDetailsView).

I even made a simple code sample for your reference according to your description.

```
<controls:MasterDetailsView
      ItemsSource="{Binding animals}">
        <controls:MasterDetailsView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding DisplayName}"></TextBlock>
            </DataTemplate>
        </controls:MasterDetailsView.ItemTemplate>
        <controls:MasterDetailsView.DetailsTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding DisplayName}"></TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}"></TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </controls:MasterDetailsView.DetailsTemplate>
        <controls:MasterDetailsView.NoSelectionContentTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="No Selection"></TextBlock>
            </DataTemplate>
        </controls:MasterDetailsView.NoSelectionContentTemplate>
    </controls:MasterDetailsView>
```

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public ObservableCollection<Animal> animals { get; set; }

    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        animals = new ObservableCollection<Animal>();
        animals.Add(new Animal() { DisplayName = "Pig", Description = "This is a pig" });
        animals.Add(new Animal() { DisplayName = "Dog", Description = "This is a dog" });
        this.DataContext = this;
    }
}

public class Animal
{
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```